# wicd use_settings_globally works but won't connect automatically

Tags: networking, wicd

I have a use case where I'd like to be able to send a pre-configured computer to a store.  The idea is that the end user shouldn't have to plug in a keyboard and mouse unless absolutely necessary.

I am able to pre-configure wicd up until a point where I only have to click 'connect' in the wicd GUI to get onto the network.

My understanding is that setting `use_settings_globally = 1` should allow clients to connect to any network by essid, instead of default bssid (mac address).  However when I try to demonstrate/test this, I still need to hit 'connect' to make the connection.

I found the setting `should_verify_ap` in the settings but wasn't able to find any documentation on this one.   Does anyone know anything about that? I did try toggling it to no avail.

Here's my wireless-settings.conf.

```
[essid:HEREISANSSID]
afterscript = None
dhcphostname = my-computer
bssid = 28:CF:E9:**:**:**
ip = None
dns_domain = None
gateway = None
use_global_dns = False
encryption = True
postdisconnectscript = None
beforescript = None
hidden = False
channel = 11
mode = Master
netmask = None
key = PASSWORD
usedhcphostname = 0
predisconnectscript = None
bitrate = auto
enctype = wpa-psk
allow_lower_bitrates = 0
dns3 = None
dns2 = None
dns1 = None
use_settings_globally = True
use_static_dns = False
apsk = PASSWORD
encryption_method = WPA2
essid = HEREISANSSID
automatic = 1
search_domain = None
```

When I use this to connect to a network, it adds similar entries with the BSSID heading.

Here's my manager-settings.conf

```
[Settings]
backend = external
wireless_interface = wlp1s0
wired_interface = None
wpa_driver = wext
always_show_wired_interface = False
use_global_dns = False
global_dns_1 = None
global_dns_2 = None
global_dns_3 = None
global_dns_dom = None
global_search_dom = None
auto_reconnect = True
debug_mode = 0
wired_connect_mode = 1
signal_display_type = 0
should_verify_ap = 1
dhcp_client = 0
link_detect_tool = 0
flush_tool = 0
sudo_app = 0
prefer_wired = False
show_never_connect = True
```

I need to be able to connect to an ESSID without ever having known the BSSID.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some probing in the `wicd-daemon.py` and found the code block relevant to auto-connect.

I searched some of the code there which lead me to https://bugs.launchpad.net/wicd/+bug/1440952

I substituted the code in and viola, I can connect networks configured with the same ESSID.

```
     for x, network in enumerate(self.LastScan):
        - if self.config.has_section(network['bssid']):
        + essid_key = "essid:%s" % network['essid']
        + if self.config.has_section(network['bssid']) or self.config.has_section(essid_key):
                        if self.debug_mode:
                            print network["essid"] + ' has profile'
                        if bool(network.get('automatic')):
```